# How to access data outside of a Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a react app that sends an API call to OpenWeather to get the weather data for a city (specified by the user). Here's what the request for that call looks like:

```
async function getAPI()  {

  const apiCall = await axios.get(apiLink).then(res => {

    res = {
   
      temp : res.data.main.temp - 273.15,
      weatherIcon : res.data.weather[0].icon,
      windSpeed : res.data.wind.speed
  
    }
  
  return res
  });

return apiCall

}

const weatherData = getAPI()
```

Notice that I try to store the data I want from the API response in a variable called weatherData. That way I can simply call that variable whenever I need, heres an example of HTML code that uses this variable:

```
<p>
    temperature is {weatherData.temp} Celcius 
</p>
```

This results in weatherData.temp simply not showing up on the browser side for some reason. A console.log(weatherData) prints this in the console:

```
Promise {<pending>}
 [[Prototype]]: Promise
 [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
 [[PromiseResult]]: Object
   temp: 29.53
   weatherIcon: "04d"
   windSpeed: 1.59
 [[Prototype]]: Object
```

How do I extract the data from the promise in a way that allows me to easily refer to said data for use in HTML code?

Comment: Do you understand the concept of setting state etc? If so you should be utilizing state as opposed to variables to render your data in JSX.

Answer (score 1):

Answer below is if you are using functional components and react hooks.

You can can go two directions:

1. Using a try catch block:

```
const fetchWeather = async () => {
 try {
   const res = await axios.get(apiLink);
   console.log(res);
   setWeather(res.data); //Im not sure what the exact response is, but you can access the keys you need.
   // you can then set the data you need to your state to render it.
 } catch (error) {
   // handle error
 }
}
```

Or you can use .then .catch

```
const fetchWeather = async () => {
  axios.get(apiLink)
    .then((res) => {
    setWeather(res.data); //Im not sure what the exact response is, but you can access the keys you need.
      // set the data you need from the respones to your state.
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle error
    })
}
```

In both cases you can just call the function in your useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetchWeather()
}, [])
```

In general my preference goes to set the response you get from the Api into the local state (meaning the state of your page/component). And then rendering the state to your jsx.

So if you are using react hooks, your state could look like this:

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
```

Last Edit:
Finally you can just refer to your state within your jsx/html. Assuming your weather state looks like this:

```
{
 temp: '50 degrees'
}
```

In your JSX you can just refer to it this way:

```
<>
 <div>{weather.temp}</div>
</>
```